# Which programming language is similar to PHP?

Tags: php

I'm good at PHP, and I want to learn a programming language. I remember there was a programming language that's similar to PHP. I forgot if it was C++, Python, or something else.

Comment: Syntax wise C++ is pretty similar. Python is a scripting language like php and more similar in functionality, you should say whether you want a compiled language or a scripting language.

Comment: Probably Perl is what you're thinking of. But I suggest learning a language unlike PHP to broaden your programming skills. Maybe try Haskell or Clojure or some other functional language

Comment: @SeanNilan I agree about learning a language unlike PHP, but I disagree with your language choice suggestions.  Face it, most of the market in use today uses Java or some C based language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is similar, but more complex.  Read over the manual before you get started, it will save you a lot of headaches: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: Heck no. C++ is *far* more structured than PHP.

Comment: PHP isn't really that similar to C++ (or C, Obj C, or whatever other Cs you might come up with). PHP has dynamically typed variables where C++ does not, etc. Things like that make PHP much different (and easier to learn) than C.

Comment: I guess going the other direction (C++ to PHP) makes more sense.  [link](http://forum.codecall.net/php-development/15637-php-compared-c.html#post148456)